# Could not load the file or assembly | Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I need to add a custom dll which will provide me with Data Matrix generation but for some reason it gives me this error... [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmSIQ.png)

It says "Could not load the file or assembly 'C: \ Windows \ System32 \ cruflbcs.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."

I added the file to every single folder possible, did the 'regsvr32' command and it gave a successful response.

I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Remotely, this file should be pushed to following location:

```
 %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\<VERSION>.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin
```

Locally, this should be placed in the following location:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio <VERSION>\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies.
```